# Npgql get_HasRows() throwing ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Good afternoon,

I`m currently developing with AspNetCore and MVC and using PostgreSQL (Npgsql) as my database.

My queries are working fine when they have some result.

When the query returns empty results, I got an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: Got unexpected message type: ReadyForQuery
   in Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.get_HasRows()
   in QueryPostgreSQL.IsEmpty()
   in sistema_cotacao.Controllers.LoginController.<Index>d__2.MoveNext() in \Visual Studio 2015\Projects\sistema-cotacao\src\sistema-cotacao\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 66
```

This is the code where the error occurs (At `query.IsEmpty()`):

```
if ((query.IsEmpty()) || (usuario.enti_email != usu.enti_email))
{
    ...
    query.Close();
    return View();
}
else
{
    ....
    query.close();
    return Redirect("/Login");
}
```

And my `IsEmpty()` function is:

```
private NpgsqlDataReader queryPostgreSQL;
...
public Boolean IsEmpty()
{
    Boolean bResult = true;
    bResult = !queryPostgreSQL.HasRows;
    return bResult;
}
```

I couldn`t find where my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Npgsql. [The issue has been fixed](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1234) and will be released in version 3.1.7 (probably later today).

Comment: I tought it was, but I wasn't sure. Thanks for your answer!